# Keyboard shortcut to move fullscreen app to second display

Tags: keyboard, display, mission-control, fullscreen

Is there any way I can set up a keyboard shortcut to move full screen apps (i.e., desktops) between my main display and my external display in OS X 10.10? I know about tools like BetterSnapTool, but it looks like it doesn't support moving full screened windows between displays. I also tried TotalSpaces and SizeUp, but unless I missed something, no dice there either.

My problem is that I have several full screened VMs from VMWare, and every time I unplug and plug in my external display, they move from my external display to my main display, and it's a pain to drag them all back every time.